# UITableView not drawing cells properly on initial load - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a table view that's in a nib file and it loads the data properly. It loads the required number of cells and fills in the data correctly. The cell is a xib file as well that includes multiple views. Each cell has a custom height. I managed to set the right height per cell using:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return (data[indexPath.row].height + 200)
}
```

The problem is that on initial load the cells don't get drawn properly like so:
[Initial load image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wU4Si.png)

The description area doesn't move where I made it move by changing its X and Y coordinates.

This gets fixed however when I scroll the table view beyond the initially loaded cells and go back to them, like so:
[After scrolling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/exV8b.png)

Upon loading the cell I move the description area below the image. This works for cells but not on the initially loaded ones. It only gets fixed once I scroll the broken cells out of view and go back to them. How do I fix this? How can I make it so that the cells get drawn properly on the initial load?

Edit: To clarify: The cells get loaded properly but aren't drawn correctly. I have to scroll out of the first few cells and scroll back to them for the cells to be drawn right.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: what is "data" ?

Comment: a dictionary variable that I use as the data source of the table. It has a height property for its image so that I can set the height of the table row

Answer (score 1):

I can see that the image you'r trying to load is of larger dimension than that of the image container view.
You can try giving clipsToBound = True to the imageView.

This would most probably resolve your issue.
Thanks.

Comment: Yes the image is larger than the container view. I tried adding clipsToBound but the same thing still happens. Thank you though

Answer (score 0):

you want to increase `UITableViewCell` height based on image inside it, right?

Here is tableview datasource and delegate.

extension MyDataSource: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if let height = self.rowHeights[indexPath.row] {
        return height
    } else {
        return 100
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if let height = self.rowHeights[indexPath.row] {
        return height
    } else {
        return 100
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return mydatas.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let mydata = mydatas[indexPath.row]

    var cell: UITableViewCell
    cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: 'myCell.cellIdentify()')!
    cell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    cell.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.selectionStyle = .none

    let image = UIImage(named: promotion)
    (cell as! myCell).configureCell(downloadImage: image!)
    let aspectRatio = (image?.size.height)!/(image?.size.width)!
    let imageHeight = (cell.contentView.frame.width * aspectRatio) + 16

    UIView.performWithoutAnimation {
        self.myTableView?.beginUpdates()
        self.rowHeights[indexPath.row] = imageHeight
        self.myTableView?.endUpdates()
    }

    return cell
}
```

}

here is `UITableViewCell` custom class.

**myCell**

```
import UIKit

class myCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var imageHolder: WMView!
    @IBOutlet weak var actionImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var loaderIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView!

    override func prepareForReuse() {
        super.prepareForReuse()
        self.loaderIndicator.isHidden = false
        self.loaderIndicator.startAnimating()
        self.actionImage.image = nil
    }

    static func cellHeight() -> CGFloat {
        return 73.0
    }

    static func cellIdentify() ->String {
        return "myCell"
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
    }

    func configureCell(downloadImage: UIImage) {
        self.imageHolder.layer.borderWidth = 1
        self.imageHolder.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        self.imageHolder.layer.borderColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor

        self.imageHolder.layer.masksToBounds = true
        self.imageHolder.clipsToBounds = true

        //ImageHolder
        self.actionImage.image = downloadImage
        self.loaderIndicator.isHidden = true
    }
}
```

Comment: I already managed to change the cell height based on the contents successfully. What I want to happen is for the initially loaded cells to be drawn properly. Thank you though

Comment: @Chris `initially loaded cells to be drawn properly` it could not be possible because we could not know loaded image's resolution before it's loaded. But you could set `estimaterowheight` in `UITableView` instead.